# Java -- Passing ArrayList to Method and Returning

Tags: java, methods, arraylist, constructor

First -- to be clear -- this **is** homework, and I'm just trying to learn to do this properly (I don't want an answer, just guidance).  I did some searching on this site and Google at large but can't seem to find a solution.

Anyway:

In my main class, I've created an ArrayList that I'm attempting to pass to a method.  For some reason, I can't pass an ArrayList as an argument, even though the method is set up to receive one.  I'm encountering the error: "constructor in class cannot be applied to given types."

Probably I'm making a simple mistake -- can anyone help me understand what's going on here?

```
public static void main(String[] args) 

{
        Deck cards = new Deck();
        ArrayList<String> deck = new ArrayList();

        deck = cards.CreateDeck();

        Hand myHand = new Hand(deck);  //here is the error
}
```

then...

```
public class Hand {


    public static ArrayList<String> Hand (ArrayList<String> deck)
    {
        ArrayList<String> yourHand = new ArrayList<String>(deck);
        for (int i = 5; i < yourHand.size(); i++) {
            yourHand.remove(i);
        }

        return yourHand;
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see you invoking the `Hand(ArrayList<String>)` method anywhere.

Comment: The correct format is `Hand myHand = Hand.Hand(deck);`. If you wanted to make this a constructor, then your Hand class should have this `public Hand (ArrayList<String> deck){...}`

Comment: Or rather `ArrayList<String> myHand = Hand.Hand(deck);`

Comment: I think your intention is to pass the deck in a constructor, but constructor cannot have return value.

Comment: You have used `Hand` as the name of your method. Java naming standards use a lowercase letter as the first character of a method name, ie `hand`. Consider following this guideline - ie `public static List<String> hand (List<String> deck)` - others will more readily understand your code. Also, notice the use of `List` as the type, not `ArrayList` - see [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Comment: AGH!  I figured it out!  Please disregard!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to pass the `Arraylist` in `Hand` class constructor but there is no constructor which accept list in `Hand` class.

You need to do something like this in `Hand` class

```
private List<String> deck;
public Hand (List<String> deck) {
    this.deck = deck;
}
```

Comment: well that's an interesting syntax :) Scala?

Comment: He doesn't seem to want to pass the deck to a constructor though; he seems to want to just manipulate it with a static method.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: Actually the problem is that it's very unclear at the moment what he wants.

Comment: @sstan True, but it's clear he's trying to pass an array list to a static method. `deck` is never a field in his example, so I seriously doubt this is close to his intent.

Comment: Agree with sstan. We all have suggested different ways now it's up to him how he would like to correct

Comment: Nvm. I looked over the example again, and I'm even more confused about the intent.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to instantiate a Hand using a static method, which doesn't work.

If your intent is to just pass an `ArrayList` to a method that is inside of `Hand`, do the following:

Change the method's name to something else (that doesn't start with a capital), and get rid of the `new` keyword in the `main`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
        Deck cards = new Deck();
        ArrayList<String> deck = new ArrayList();

        deck = cards.CreateDeck();

        //You had Hand as a method, which can't be initialized!
        List<String> changedDeck = doSomethingWithDeck(deck);
}
```

Then, your class with the static method would look like:

```
public class Hand {


    public static ArrayList<String> doSomethingWithDeck(ArrayList<String> deck)
    {
        ArrayList<String> yourHand = new ArrayList<String>(deck);
        for (int i = 5; i < yourHand.size(); i++) {
            yourHand.remove(i);
        }

        return yourHand;
    }

}
```

But, if your intent is to actually create a hand, you'll need to explain what your intent is, because constructors can't be static, and can't return a value.

Answer (score 0):

Constructors cannot have return types, nor can they be `static`.
What you have actually defined is a class method, which can be called without instantiating a `Hand` object. Calling `Hand.Hand(deck)` will return an `ArrayList<String>`, not a `Hand` object. Also, the method should not have the same name as the class.